# How to stop reducer key being a key in itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

basically I always have this problem whereby as reducers are keys of the object store

they are accessed like `this.props.users` for examples

so if users state is an array, this is fine

`const initialState = []`

but if I have this:

```
const initialState = {
  users: [],
  loading: false,
  error: ""
};
```

coz you know, my reducer needs to do a few more things

then suddenly I have this horrible thing all over my codebase where I'm doing things like:

`this.props.users.users` clearly, disgusting. how can I get it back to `this.props.users` but then able to access the other stuff as well?

one example of reducer code case:

```
case FETCHING_USERS_SUCCEEDED: {
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    users: [].concat(...state.users).concat(action.userData)
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you post the reducer code that populates the `users` array?

Comment: @AlanFriedman yeh one sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you map your state to props, map state.users.users instead of just state.users.

Comment: that seems like a solution of sorts. surely a better way though?

Comment: actually wait that wont work coz of the other keys in the initial state surely?

Comment: `state` refers to the global redux state, `users` refers to the reducer's state, and `users` (second) refers to the property on that reducer's state. You are wanting only a particular property of that reducer's state, so you should just pass that particular property.

Answer (score 2):

you can declare user as a variable like this

```
const {users} = this.props.users
```

> thereafter you can use **users** instead of **this.props.users.users**

Comment: problem comes when I wanna use this.props.users.loading

Comment: then use like this const {users} = this.props, so you can use users.loading instead of this.props.users.loading

Comment: still have users.users that way though

Comment: you can change the key in combine reducer